# Parallers: Copy and Paste not working in the Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, clipboard, parallels, windows-server-2016

I have latest Parallels installed to MacBook and I'running Windows Server 2016 on it, but I have issues with clipboard.
This issues is not about coping from Mac to Windows issues. I also have copy and paste working fine in Chrome and Notepad.
prl_cc.exe is running ok.

However clipboard does not work in the address bar of Microsoft Internet Explorer!  When I open google site and clipboard can be used normally in goole in IE. What could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot please? server versions of windows run IE in an Enhanced Protected mode. Use a windows client version and IE11 to test your web apps. see browserstack.com for free Emulators.

Comment: I have added screen shot. So problem is that Copy and paste of IE address bar does not work in SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows that you are using a windows 2016 VM. The default security settings of IE for server versions of windows use an "Enhanced security mode".

IE browsers use "Security Zones" (lists of hosts), to control browser and web site security, including the ability to copy/paste text.

See Tools>Internet Options>Security tab.... Custom settings. Compare the default security zone settings on a client version and a server version and you will see that server versions of IE 11 and client versions are different.

You should not use server versions of IE and visual studio to develop on localhost.. (you could sign-on with the Admin account, but even the admin account on IE on server versions is severely hawked).

To learn or develop internet/intranet applications,

**Use a Client version of windows (windows 7, 8.1,10) VM's to test/develop or learn web based or intranet applications on your MACs.**